# C# Label not visible in GroupBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a loop that is supposed to go through DataTable and for each row create a new GroupBox, set it's text to value from one column, in that GroupBox I want to put a Label with Text similar to another column in the table. 
This is just part of the code!

```
for (int i = 0; i < tab.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    lblbox[i] = new GroupBox();
    lblbox[i].Text = tab.Rows[i]["text"].ToString();
    lblbox[i].Name = "box no " + i.ToString();
    lblbox[i].Visible = true;        
    this.Controls.Add(lblbox[i]);
    lblbox[i].Location = new Point(5, 55 * i);
    lblbox[i].Height = 50;
    lblbox[i].SendToBack();
    importancelbl[i] = new Label();
    importancelbl[i].Text = "Importance: " + tab.Rows[i]["importance"].ToString();
    importancelbl[i].Name = "implbl" + i.ToString();
    importancelbl[i].Visible = true;
    lblbox[i].Controls.Add(importancelbl[i]);
    importancelbl[i].BringToFront();
    Point locP = new Point();
    locP.X = lblbox[i].Location.X + 5;
    locP.Y = lblbox[i].Location.Y + 15;
    importancelbl[i].Location = locP;
```

}

When i run the code it creates three (I have three rows in my table) GroupBoxes correctly and creates all the labels, **but only first label** is visible in its Groupbox. When I add those labels to the Form and not to the GroupBox, all of them are visible, but I want them to be in boxes... 
I've tried pretty much everything and I'm still very confused (espacially by the behavior of the first label). I know the mistake is probably obvious and stupid, but I just can't find it!

Comment: When you are nesting controls, I think the locations are locations *within that contorl*, so when a label is within the group box, you would set the location of the label to be the location within the groupbox.

Comment: I usually set the location before adding the control to the container.    Otherwise Patko is probably right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Control.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx) is relative to its parent, so set `Location` for the label to (5, 15).

```
locP.X = 5;
locP.Y = 15;
```

Comment: Thank you. I said it was going to be stupid. I didn't realise that i starts at 0 so the first label would be set correctly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that they are somehow overlapping and making each other disappear somehow.

Could you try posting pictures of the form when it works and when it doesn't? Also add all your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to preform adding

```
lblbox[i].Controls.Add(importancelbl[i]);
this.Controls.Add(lblbox[i]);
```

after setting all your properties

Comment: I've tried all that, Patko's answer is the right one, but thank you.